# How to write an array[variable] with a variable size the user can enter?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program, which reads a polynomial.
I use C with Visual Studio 10(at work)/13(at home)

Code:

```
void getPolynomial()
{
    int number;//Quantity of the polynomial
    number = getInt(1, 10);
        //getInt(min, max) Read a number from the user 
        //and return an int value between min and max
    double poly[] = poly[number];
        //I try to fix this line. 
        //It should create an array with as many fields,
        //as the user wants to have.
}
```

gives

> error C2075: 'poly' : array initialization needs curly braces

If I try:

```
double poly[number];
```

I get:

> error C2057: expected constant expression
>
> error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
>
> error C2133: 'poly' : unknown size

This is the solution, special thanks to CoolGuy

```
#include<stdlib.h>

void getPolynomial()
{
    int number;
    double *poly;
    number = getInt(1, 10);
    poly = malloc(number * sizeof(*poly));
    // use array poly[]
    free(poly);
}
```

Comment: You can't with Microsoft's compiler. Requires a C compiler that supports C99 or above. Use a dynamic allocation.

Comment: `siceof` should be `sizeof` in the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double poly[] = poly[number];
```

is not valid C. You have to use

```
double poly[number];
```

if your compiler supports C99. The above line creates a VLA(Variable Length Array) and this was introduced in C99. AFAIK, VS 2010 does not support C99, but VS 2013 does.

If that doesn't work you'll have to dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`/`calloc`:

```
double *poly;
poly = malloc(number * sizeof(*poly)); //sizeof(*poly)==sizeof(double)

//After poly's use,

free(poly);
```

Comment: Last VS compilers implements only parts of C99 (the parts that are also in C++).

Comment: I've never used VS. So, since VLAs aren't part of C++, it isn't valid in new VS compilers?

Comment: No, it isn't. Is there another way, like including something or write a function for it?

Comment: Yes. Use `double poly[SOME_MEANINGFUL_SIZE];`. This is the worst approach. The best ones are `malloc`/VLA. No other option available!

Comment: btw, what does the star in double *poly; mean?

Comment: It signifies that `poly` is a pointer of type `double*`. In simple words, `poly` is a pointer to `double`. Look up on pointers for more info about this.